# Best number of epochs when all the dataset is fed to a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

When a MLP model is trained using a training and validation dataset, we can know the number of epochs that best fits the model. Once the training is done, and we know the best number of epochs, in order to get the best mlp model, would be fine if the model is retrained not only with the training set but the entire data set with the same number of epochs, so the model can see more data?  Or this number of epochs could result in a good MLP model for the first approach but in an overfitted one for the second?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a single approach to that. It depends on factors such as validation strategy (e.g. k-fold cross-validation vs validation set as the test set itself), if the model is [learning on the fly or offline](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/static-vs-dynamic-training/video-lecture), if there is biased or imbalanced data on the validation set.

You may find useful the following sources:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-on-the-full-dataset-after-cross-
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-on-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402055/fitting-after-training-and-validation
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361494/how-to-correctly-retrain-model-using-all-data-after-cross-validation-with-early
- https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/7xqszr/should_final_model_be_retrained_on_full_dataset/
- https://www.quora.com/Should-we-train-neural-networks-on-the-training-set-combined-with-the-validation-set-after-tuning